# Q-Q plots and the genomic inflation factor (k)

Tags: r, statistics, limma

I have done the limma association analysis using below model design but not sure how to  evaluate Potential systematic biases using Q-Q plots and the genomic inflation factor (k). Could you please help with this?

```r
#model matrix
var<-model.matrix(~BMI + as.factor(Gender) + Age +CD8T +CD4T +NK + Bcell +Mono ,data=targets2)
fit<-lmFit(mval,var)
fit2<-eBayes(fit,trend=TRUE, robust=TRUE)
probe<-topTable(fit2,adjust="BH",coef=2,num=Inf)

write.table(probe, file = "limma.output.txt")
data <- read.delim("limma.output.txt")
head(data)

               logFC       AveExpr.    t         P.Value  adj.P.Val         B
cg03546163  0.41018776  -0.8013218  7.85104192  1.13E-12    8.65E-07    12.3051291
cg17944885  -0.4884859  2.31974279  -5.7319645  6.33E-08    0.02431349  5.15237109
```

```
#For Genomic inflation factor

# For p-values, calculate chi-squared statistic
chisq <- qchisq(1-data$P.Value,1)

#Calculate lambda gc (λgc)
median(chisq)/qchisq(0.5,1)

#QQ PLOT

library(gaston)
pdf("qq.plot.pdf", width = 12, height = 12)
qqplot.pvalues(data$P.Value)
dev.off()
```

Comment: What have you already tried? see e.g. [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/GenABEL/man/estlambda.html) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230226/how-to-manually-make-a-qq-plot-of-p-value-against-uniform-distribution) that i found by google quickly.

Comment: thank you so much @MaximilianPress, I am not sure do we need to filter limma output based on adj.P.val before running QQ plot or not? and second I am not sure how to proceed after this step.

Comment: `adj.P.val` computes q-values (or applies some other correction), so its output are not really p-values. You will need to plot the p-values themselves, not a transformation.

Comment: thanks@MaximilianPress, I updated code above for QQ plot and genomic inflation factor. I hope its correct?

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues at this point but I'll let other possibly more expert people comment.

Comment: You do not need to filter the limma output based on adj.P.Val before generating the Q-Q plot / getting the inflation factor. Your code looks good to me. Is there anything unusual about the Q-Q plot or inflation factor that makes you think something went wrong?

Comment: Thanks for all help.